# Web-based file-picker behaves differently in browser vs in WebView

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp, webforms

I have a web application with an input form, one of the fields asks the user to choose a file from their PC. I noticed that the same code opens a slightly different file picker when it's running inside a web browser (Chrome specially) versus when running inside a C# UWP WebView.

In order to demonstrate the difference, I made this sample web page to run with Node.js (based on [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp)):

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
  res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload" accept="image/*"><br>');
  res.write('</form>');
  return res.end();
}).listen(4000);
```

When I browse to it with Chrome (on Windows) and click the "choose file" button, I see this:
[image: screenshot of file picker from Chrome on Windows]
**Note that the first & default filter is "Image Files".**

So I did a basic C# UWP app which contains a WebView that navigates to this page (using the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44906551/997940)):
[image: screenshot of file picker from C# UWP]
**Note that in this case, the drop-down not only lists the file types differently (one row per each extension/type) - but it also opens on "All Files" as the first & default option.**

I already understood ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115254/997940)) that I can't remove the "All Files" option.
But is there any way to make the file picker from inside C# UWP WebView to have the filter list more like the one from Chrome browser? Or At least make that "All files" won't be the default first option?

Edit: Chromium-based [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf) could have solved this, but seems like it doesn't support UWP apps (which is my goal here), as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64703071/997940) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63107741/997940).